# Can't install Nuget package into a portable F# library, even though it is supposed to support it

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Create a blank solution.

Add a new F# project to it: Portable Class Library, Profile 7 (.NET 4.5, Windows Store, Xamarin).

Attempt to install the NuGet package `FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq`.

According to [Don Syme](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsProjectsAdmin/issues/10), this package should support Profile 7. However, running `Install-Package FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq` generates the following error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq 1.0.2'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets 
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with that framework. For more  information, contact the package
>   author. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

The project settings are as follows:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>39db5618-025a-4e44-adf4-a5eb2df04b81</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>DeleteMe</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>DeleteMe</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile7</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <TargetProfile>netcore</TargetProfile>
    <TargetFSharpCoreVersion>3.7.4.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Name>DeleteMe</Name>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a way to include this NuGet package, so that I can use `PSeq` in my Xamarin app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current nuget package only contains a net40 assembly. However master has Profile7 support and you can [download the artifacts from here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/fsprojectsgit/fsharp-collections-parallelseq/build/0.0.1.9/artifacts).

Edit: OK, it looks like this was actually released later as 1.0.1 (after 1.0.2), that's really odd. I think that updating (if that's what you call it?) from 1.0.2 to 1.0.1 will fix this for you.

Edit2: I have created [an issue here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/issues/12) to prevent this confusion going forward.

Comment: It worked. That is indeed somewhat odd. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: Glad I could help, I [have created an issue here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/issues/12) to get this fixed.